# Django Save Override Not Updating Model Instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, save

I am trying to update a model instance of my Game model every time my Bet model saves. Every time I bet saves, I'd like to add 1 to the picks field on the game model. If I print out the picks mid save override on game, it looks like it accesses and updates the number, but it doesn't save it to the database.

My hypothesis is that it's because I'm also overriding save on the game method, but when I comment this out, it still does not work. The override of save on the game model is very long, so please let me know if you see something wrong there too.

I also ended up trying post_save signals and ended up getting the same error. That code is below too.

Please let me know if you have suggestions!

Bet model:

```
class Bet(BaseModel):
    """"
    Bets on team games

    """
    size = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey('bets.PlayerProfile', null=True, blank=True, related_name='bets')
    team_game = models.ForeignKey('betting.TeamGame')
    spread_at_time = models.ForeignKey('betting.Spread', related_name="spread_bets", blank=True, null=True)
    moneyline_at_time = models.ForeignKey('betting.Moneyline', blank=True, null=True, related_name="moneyline_bets")
    winner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tag = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=128)
    # using char field to capture push
    outcome = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=128)
    pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #for pro description
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Bet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Update the number of picks to the game
        game = self.team_game.game
        game.picks += 1
        game.save()

        # Update the number of picks to the team_game
        team_game = self.team_game
        team_game.picks += 1

        # calc team pick percentage
        game_picks = self.team_game.game.picks
        team_game_picks = self.team_game.picks
        team_game.pick_pct = float(team_game_picks) / game_picks

        team_game.save()
```

Game Model:

```
class Game(BaseModel):
    """"
    Game type that holds identification, name and status
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    players = models.ManyToManyField('bets.PlayerProfile')
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('betting.Team', through='betting.TeamGame')
    final = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    sport = models.ForeignKey('betting.Sport', blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identification

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.final:

            # finds teams that bet on games
            teams = self.teamgame_set.all()
            try:

                team_a = teams[0]
                team_b = teams[1]
                # scores with spread into account
                final_a_score = team_a.score - team_a.spreads.last().value
                final_b_score = team_b.score - team_b.spreads.last().value

                # Get all the bets in this game
                bets_on_team_a = Bet.objects.filter(team_game__game=self, team_game__team=team_a)
                bets_on_team_b = Bet.objects.filter(team_game__game=self, team_game__team=team_b)

                for bet in bets_on_team_a:
                    # check spread first
                    if bet.tag == "Spread":
                        if team_a.score - bet.spread_at_time.value > team_b.score:
                            bet.winner = True
                            bet.outcome = "Win"
                            record = Record.objects.get_or_create(player=bet.player)[0]
                            record.profit += bet.size
                            record.balance += bet.size
                            record.wins += 1
                            if record.streak >= 0:
                                record.streak += 1
                            else:
                                record.streak = 1
                        if team_a.score - bet.spread_at_time.value < team_b.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Loss"
                            record = Record.objects.get_or_create(player=bet.player)[0]
                            record.profit -= bet.size
                            record.balance -= bet.size
                            record.losses += 1
                            if record.streak <=0:
                                record.streak-=1
                            else:
                                record.streak = -1
                        if team_a.score - bet.spread_at_time.value == team_b.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Push"
                            record.pushes += 1
                    else:
                        if team_a.score > team_b.score:
                            bet.winner = True
                            bet.outcome = "Win"
                            record.wins += 1
                            if record.streak >= 0:
                                record.streak += 1
                            else:
                                record.streak = 1
                        if team_a.score < team_b.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Loss"
                            record.losses += 1
                            if record.streak <=0:
                                record.streak-=1
                            else:
                                record.streak = -1
                        if team_a.score == team_b.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Push"
                            record.pushes += 1
                    bet.save()
                    record.save()

                for bet in bets_on_team_b:
                    if bet.tag == "Spread":
                        if team_b.score - bet.spread_at_time.value > team_a.score:
                            bet.winner = True
                            bet.outcome = "Win"
                            record = Record.objects.get_or_create(player=bet.player)[0]
                            record.profit += bet.size
                            record.balance += bet.size
                            record.wins += 1
                            if record.streak >= 0:
                                record.streak += 1
                            else:
                                record.streak = 1
                        if team_b.score - bet.spread_at_time.value < team_a.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Loss"
                            record = Record.objects.get_or_create(player=bet.player)[0]
                            record.profit -= bet.size
                            record.balance -= bet.size
                            record.losses += 1
                            if record.streak <=0:
                                record.streak-=1
                            else:
                                record.streak = -1
                        if team_b.score - bet.spread_at_time.value == team_a.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Push"
                            record.pushes += 1

                    # moneyline bet
                    else:
                        if team_b.score > team_a.score:
                            bet.winner = True
                            bet.outcome = "Win"
                            record = Record.objects.get_or_create(player=bet.player)[0]
                            # calc moneyline multiplier
                            multiplier = (bet.moneyline_at_time.value / 100)
                            record.profit += multiplier * bet.size
                            record.balance += multiplier * bet.size
                            record.wins += 1
                            if record.streak >= 0:
                                record.streak += 1
                            else:
                                record.streak = 1
                        if team_b.score < team_a.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Loss"
                            record.losses += 1
                            if record.streak <=0:
                                record.streak-=1
                            else:
                                record.streak = -1
                        if team_b.score == team_a.score:
                            bet.outcome = "Push"
                            record.pushes += 1
                    bet.save()
                    record.save()
```

Post Save Signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bet)
def my_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    team_game = instance.team_game
    game = team_game.game
    game.picks += 1
    game.save()
```

Comment: This is a good candidate for a `post_save` signal. You can read more on signals here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: I actually tried with no luck...will post code too